# MVC 5 ERROR but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Ninjet and Mvc. I know that error mean I am passing the wrong type to the view. but I can't figure out where is the error. here are my classes

```
 public class ProdListViewModel
{
    public ProdListViewModel()
    {
        this.ProductsList = new List<ProdViewModel>();
    }
    public ProdListViewModel(List<product> products)
    {
        this.ProductsList = new List<ProdViewModel>();

        foreach (var prod in products)
        {
            this.ProductsList.Add(new ProdViewModel(prod));


        }

    }

    public List<ProdViewModel> ProductsList { get; set; }
}

 public class ProdViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int productsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string pname { get; set; }

    public ProdViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ProdViewModel(product product)
    {
        productsID = product.productsID;
        pname = product.pname;

    }
}
```

this is my control. as you can see I am using ninjet. I check I am returning to product a list of 2 product. but

```
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
     internal readonly IProductRepository productRepository;


     public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }
    // GET: Product
    public ActionResult FrontPageList()

    {
```

//here I get the product from repository and bring only 2
            var product = productRepository.Products.Take(2).OrderBy(p => p.productsID).ToList();

```
        return View(new ProdListViewModel(product));
    }
}
```

here is the view I generate by VS

```html
@model IEnumerable<SalesRep.Domain.ViewModels.TuscanyWeb.ProdListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FrontPageList";
}

<h2>FrontPageList</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

this is the complete error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SalesRep.Domain.ViewModels.TuscanyWeb.ProdListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SalesRep.Domain.ViewModels.TuscanyWeb.ProdListViewModel]'

on the other hand if in the controller I to this

```
//List<ProdViewModel> basicObjectList =
        //     product.ConvertAll(x => new ProdViewModel
        //     {
        //         pname = x.pname,
        //          productsID = x.productsID
        //     });
```

and pass basicObjectList to the view i works fine.

Comment: Could you please also post your `FrontPageList.cshtml` template?

Comment: I edit the question with the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@model IEnumerable<SalesRep.Domain.ViewModels.TuscanyWeb.ProdListViewModel>`, just `@model SalesRep.Domain.ViewModels.TuscanyWeb.ProdListViewModel`. Then, in your for loop just do it like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList ) {
```

Comment: Thank you that works great. wow. so. Question , when I create a view from template in visual studio, I cant not select List, what I should select then? or I have to do my view manually?

Comment: Creating your view manually is your best option. Please upvote this answer and/or make it as accepted answer.